# Python script to iterate over a directory of files and append files tha tmatch a pattern

Tags: python

I have some csv files in my windows directory that are separated by month e.g:

```
C:\201801\customerlist_201801;
C:\201802\customerlist_201802;
...
..
.
C:\201810\customerlist_201810;
```

Not all directories will have a file. I need a python script that will iterate over the directories(start with a user provided month:201801, then increment it by 1 every time), pick up the file , and keep appending to produce a single file which is a concatenation of all the files.

Can you provide some pointers where to begin?
Is it easier to do it using Windows programming (i.e cmd line scripts)?
All the folders have other subfolders and files.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a basic solution**

```
files = ["C:\\%d\\customerlist_%d"%(i,i) for i in range(201801,201810)]
for file in files:
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        info = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        info_types = []
        records = 0
        for row in info:
            #Here you can process them as you like i.e append the content
```